# Scroll ONLY Overflown Text in Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, autocomplete

Is there any way to **scroll on focus only the overflown autocomplete suggestions?** Right now **my code animates short items as well, which is something I don't want**. Check out the snippet below to see what I mean.

```js
$("#ac").autocomplete({
  source: [
    "someveryve rylonglongword",
    "someveryverylong longwordsomeveryverylonglongword",
    "someshortword",
  ]
});
```

```css
.ui-menu-item {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.ui-menu-item a {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 1s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ui-menu-item a.ui-state-focus{ 
  width: auto; 
  transform: translateX(calc(200px - 100%));}

.ui-widget-content a.ui-state-focus {
  margin: -1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
  <h3>Type "s" to start</h3>
  <input type="text" id="ac" />
</div>
```